# Ordering data with arrays

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, getjson

Good Evening,

I am loading a number of ticker codes from a database using the following code:

```
$username='root';
$password='password';
try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=stock_d1', $username, $password);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM holding_t1 WHERE view ="yes" ORDER BY id'; 
foreach($conn->query($sql) as $row) {

  }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
die();
}
```

I am then using JQuery's getJSON function to pull the corresponding data via YQL using the following:

```
$.getJSON('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?   q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22' + $EPIC + '%22)&format=json &env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=?', 
     function(data) { console.log(data);  
                     var ask = data.query.results.quote.AskRealtime; 
                     var bid = data.query.results.quote.BidRealtime; 
                     var name = data.query.results.quote.Name; 
                     ; } );
```

Where YHOO is replaced with the respective ticker code taken from the database (assuming in this instance that the variable is $EPIC).

If I echo out the line of Javascript, the results do not return in order of ID but rather time taken to retrieve via the callback.  I am considering passing the data to an array and then using that to dictate the order.  I am interested in hearing if this is the best way to approach this and if so, the best way of doing it.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions and continued patience.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a function to manage when they're added:

```
var waiting = {};
var next = 0;

var addItem = function(id, item) {
    waiting[id] = item;

    while(item = waiting[next]) {
        console.log(item); // Or whatever you need to do with it
        next++;
    }
};
```

And then:

```
… function(data) {
    addItem(itemId, data.query.results.quote);
});
```

Note that you'll need to associate each item with its ID relative to the rest to make them appear in sequence like this.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I've been trying to get my head around your suggestion.  Assuming ID is the name of the field for each associated ID, I am unsure of how this would be implemented.  At which stage would this association be made?

Comment: @PadLarkin: It should most likely be made wherever `$EPIC` comes from; just assign to `itemId` there. (And if it's in a loop, beware the loop scoping thing.)